# Random question protection

Tags: discussion, protected-questions

There seem to be quite a few very old, very good questions that are being needlessly 'protected' for some reason recently. These questions are popular reading, it seems from the number of views, but given that some of these questions are four years old, and they have not been littered with bad answers or silly comments, I do not understand why they are being protected.

Protecting these questions only does one thing, which is prevent them from being answered by new users. This is not doing a service to the site. Far from it, it is doing a disservice to future readers and  deterring new members. Can we use the protection privilege more judiciously please?

What can we do about questions that have been needlessly protected?

Comment: If one scrolls down, down, down one often finds a VLQ answer (sometimes it's VVLQ) recently posted by an unregistered user.

Comment: What is the purpose then of protection at all? (What does the FAQ say?)

Comment: @ab2 What's a VLQ?

Comment: @Mitch 'Questions should be protected when they are garnering lots of views and newbies are adding "me too!", "thanks!" and possibly even spam non-answers.' That isn't the case with these protections. Most of the questions only have good answers and sensible comments.

Comment: VLQ means Very Low Quality.  (I made up VVLQ -- Very, very low quality.)  Often the Very Low Quality Answer is still there, but if several days have passed since the protection, it may have been flagged and deleted.

Comment: @ab2 But I've already said that this isn't the case with these question - otherwise I would not be posting this question here!!! [The only reason I'm not linking to them directly is that I don't want to personalise the issue by seeming to 'name' the random 'protectors'.]

Comment: I noticed the uptick in protections of old questions too.  I haven't counted how many of the newly protected old questions have recent VLQ answers by new users, and how many don't.  (I've seen a few awful recent answers to old questions that made me wish I had protection powers.)  Without examples of protected good old questions with only sensible answers, I don't see how the discussion can proceed productively.  You have a valid question, which a possibly overly protective high-rep user should not mind answering.

Comment: You've 20k rep. Please see if there are recently deleted low-quality answers under the said "protected questions". If yes, then protection was justified. Else, I agree that we're being overprotective and it is a problem.

Comment: @NVZ Not on the most recent one that made me post this question. But in any case, one poor answer every four to twenty years is not a good reason to protect a question. We don't do that with brand new questions that get one bad answer. It's not really a good reason to protect a question.

Comment: Sometimes the very low quality answers get deleted, so take a look at the bottom of the page and see who are the culprits, you might find the deletion date coincides with the protection. Then let's not forget the spam answers, the vulgar and abusive answers from unregistered users, these will always be deleted but to prevent our friends from returning and posting a second answer, which does happen, it's best to "protect" these questions. The problem is when you have what *looks* like a Low Quality Answer but is in actual fact a gem, but that question gets protected all the same.

Comment: You need to include examples of posts, which you perceive are being protected too hasily. I am willing to put myself on the line, I've protected many a question in the past, it's a necessary evil. But to me, **protect** is not not synonymous with **no to new answers**. To me *protect* means **we don't want the quality of this page to be soiled or lowered** by trolls and time wasters. I might be wrong in this interpretation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If you have a look at the answer below, you'll get the nub of the problem. 'Protection' is designed to prevent highly popular questions from being deluged with low quality answers or comments - mostly usefully applied within the first few days of a question's life. Indeed you mention that protect means 'we don't want the quality of this page to be soiled or lowered by trolls and time wasters', implying that a) there is some urgency and b) the risk is high because of the popularity of the question and c) that the question has merit.

Comment: @Mari-LouA But it seems that protection is being used as an alternative to closure. I don't think that we should protect old questions every time we get a low quality answer to one. :(

Comment: @Araucaria I think it is a matter of how you interpret the guidelines. What I find very difficult to understand is why you used the word "random". If you find any question that was randomly protected by any user, the user should be flagged for moderator's attention as (s)he is abusing their privileges. Other than that, closing and protecting have more merits than demerits.

Comment: @Rathony Of course, things that seem random may not be! I don't believe in knee-jerk flagging to mods, in addition to which, I may be misguided. The reason that many of the recent protections seemed random to me is that I never thought anyone would interpret *'Questions should be protected when they are garnering lots of views and newbies are adding "me too!", "thanks!" and possibly even spam non-answers.'* as applying to very old questions which  which are no longer garnering lots of views and which have recently attracted *one* LQA from a newbie. I couldn't see the reason for protecting.

Comment: @Araucaria As I mentioned below, "bad questions always lead to bad answers". I firmly believe those newbies answer those questions because the questions look easier to answer than other questions. Those newbies, far more often than not, are spammers and they never come back to answer or ask another question. They just randomly find a question and abuse their right to answer whatever question they want. If they are serious enough to stay on this community, earning 10 reputation points is a piece of cake. I don't think protecting should be used for closing. Closable questions should be closed.

Comment: @Rathony  May I edit your comments into my question?

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, please. Why not?

Comment: @ab2 If you see any question that you think should be protected, please don't hesitate to post a comment to any of my posts. I will do it on your behalf.

Comment: @Araucaria Do you think it is OK to protect this question? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186446/what-is-the-single-word-for-a-school-where-only-boys-study

Comment: There are now three votes in favour of closing the question which Rathony cites in his answer. Once that question is closed, then there will be no new answers. Protecting a question, whether it is a week old or five years old does not prevent users from posting answers. Closures do.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Do you mean the question is not closable? What do you think of the two answers? What action did you take for the two answers?

Comment: I feel very strongly that we should leave the [perdure, endure, persist](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78136/endure-vs-perdure-vs-persist) question open. It is a very old question, and it met the standards of its time. PLUS, the distinction between perdure and endure is not completely explained in the answers (@tchrist) and we should not close off the chance of wrapping this up with a flourish

Comment: @Araucaria Protection is to stop under 15 rep users from posting answers, to prevent expected crap/VLQ answers. Protection is about bad _answers_, not about questions. Closing is about bad _questions_. 15 rep prevents drive-by google searchers, people who have no idea about expected behavior here, from adding crap answers. It's easy for someone to get above fifteen by getting a feel for the site first.

Comment: @Araucaria Protection is to stop absolute first time visitors from answering. If you don't like that then you don't like the entire idea of 'protecting' (which may be supportable but is an entirely different discussion).

Comment: @Mitch It is [10 reputation points](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user). Just one answer with an upvote, one question with two upvotes, five successful edits. Those who don't want to make such efforts to cross this unbelievably easy threshold don't deserve any right to post an answer to old questions.

Comment: @Mitch Yeah, but it's meant to be there for a reason. Not just for the sake of it or because one person has given a LQA.

Comment: @Mitch where on Stack Exchange does it say that *protection* was created to stop absolute first time visitors from answering?  If that is the case then every question that passes the 12 month mark should be automatically protected, but they're not, hence it means that even new answers from new members are welcomed. I didn't have 100 rep when I first started, and for weeks I was too scared to suggest edits. I started by answering questions.

Comment: Protection **is** there for a reason. It's to stop LQ answers once a question has been bumped by a LQ answer from a newbie who thinks "I know that." It only prevents answers from new members; it doesn't prevent questions, or comments, or members with more than 10 rep earned on the site (ie 11+ or 111+ rep) from answering. It's generally used like that, reactively; it is occasionally used pre-emptively on an especially provocative question.

Comment: I'd like to categorically state I did not delete my reply to Rathony's provocation: *What do you think of the two answers? What action did you take for the two answers?* So, for the umpteenth time, because it is a frequent accusation that he launches at me, I am not a marshall on EL&U, I am not under any obligation whatsoever to take action whenever I meet  a low quality answer or question. The time I spend reading answers and questions is my own, and how I choose to spend that time, is my own, whether to intervene with a DV, leave a comment or simply ignore a weak post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is a member expected to protect a question?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6756/when-is-a-member-expected-to-protect-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to this question, ["endure" vs "perdure" vs "persist"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78136/endure-vs-perdure-vs-persist)

The reasons I decided to protect it:

1. The question reads more like general reference without any research efforts. I think it should be closed. I thought about whether to close-vote it or protect it and I chose the latter as it is a very old question.
2. There are two answers from one-reputation users and two deleted answers, all of which are sub-standard. (Please read my comments to the two answers). I judged it is enough to trigger protection.
3. I judged it would be very unlikely for the question to have a meaningful and well-researched answer from a new user as @tchrist's answer seems to be the right answer.

The only benefit of protecting a question is blocking new users with one reputation or 101 reputation points with an association bonus of 100 from answering a question. Other than that, there is nothing beneficial or non-beneficial to this site.

What I don't understand is why you think protecting a question is doing disservice to this community and why it would deter new members.

**There are tens of thousands of questions that are neither closed nor protected**.

I have rarely seen good answers posted by new users to an old question. Do you think there is a chance of a well-researched and helpful answer being posted to the question?

Also, you need to note that **you have every right to unprotect any question** that you find unduly protected.

I just found another protected question, [What does "five O" mean (and why)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33406/what-does-five-o-mean-and-why) It was protected right after the second low-quality answer was posted. I don't see any problem protecting this question as it is again general reference.

**Low-quality questions always lead to low-quality answers.**

Comment: Better protected than closed!  There is room for an answer that does a better job of explaining the difference between perdure and endure. "perdure has more “throughness” to it, implying that something has not just endured, but in fact persisted through or despite something else"  and "endure implies effort, feeling, resistance against opposition" (different user).  I'll look it up for myself, but what I am saying is that an answer that will add to this question is not likely to come from a new user.  Of course, nothing is certain.

Comment: @ab2 I think you hit the nail with "an answer that will add to this question is not likely to come from a new user." I wish I could see just one answer that adds something valuable to an old question. I really wanted to use "never" instead of "rarely" in my answer.

Comment: As to whether the question is general reference -- no, not with such an obscure word as perdure and (I hate saying nuanced) but such a nuanced difference between perdure and endure.

Comment: @ab2 Well, I am not even sure whether "to perdure" is used in contemporary English and this [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=perdure%2C+endure%2C+persist&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cperdure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cendure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpersist%3B%2Cc0) shows it is not that broadly used. The reason why I said it's general reference is there are no research efforts or example sentence where the OP found the word. It is just "what's the difference?" I think one user agrees with me and voted to close it just now.

Comment: I concur with this answer. Adding a VLQ answer to an old question bumps it in the "active" question list, which can encourage other poor answers. Protection stops new members from adding further posts of dubious quality -- and if the potential poster can write good answers, then he can answer another question well in order to gain the 10 rep needed to overcome the protection.

Comment: @AndrewLeach But if the question was likely to garner lots of LQAs it would have done so in the original instance. Most new posters are tempted on by a particular Q, so deterring someone who wants to contribute to a particular answer is just deterring them altogether. There are good examples of people protecting Qs (in fact, this used to be one area that worked seemlessly). Basically look at any of Reg, Tchrist or Matt's protections. They're the type of protections that need to be applied, imo. i.e. they are applied early on to stop a run of low quality answers and comments.

Comment: @Araucaria I think you are mistaken. Reg. Tchrist, Matt all protected a question long after it was posted. There are hundreds of them, maybe thousands like this one. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106582/when-to-use-nude-and-when-naked and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125/when-should-into-be-used-rather-than-in-to-and-vice-versa. You can review old questions and see how protection has been working so far. We don't need to care about those spammers and good newbies like you and myself will find a way to answer a question if we are hell-bent on answering them.